# How do I bootstrap a plugin on TYPO3 CMS 6.0 with extbase?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase

I'm trying to use an extbase plugin through typoscript on TYPO3 CMS 6.0. I used the following code, that I found repeated all over the web:

```
10 = USER
10 { 
    userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
    pluginName = Sermons
    extensionName = VmfdsSermons
    switchableControllerActions {
        Sermon {
            1 = byLatestSeries
            2 = list
            3 = show
    }
}
```

However, this just gives me the following error:

```
#1289386765: Could not analyse class:Tx_VmfdsSermons_Controller_SermonController maybe not loaded or no autoloader?
```

It seems to me as if `tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run` is not using namespaces yet, thus trying to load a class called `Tx_VmfdsSermons_Controller_SermonController` when it should have called `\TYPO3\VmfdsSermons\Controller\SermonController`. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're searching for the property `vendorName`. So in your case it should be:

```
10 = USER
10 { 
    userFunc      = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run

    pluginName    = Sermons
    extensionName = VmfdsSermons
    vendorName    = TYPO3
    [...]
```

I also used the vendor namespace within `ext_localconf.php`:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    '<Vendor>.' . $_EXTKEY, 
    [...]
```

I found the answer by using the debugger. I started at `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Dispatcher::resolveController()` and jumped into `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request::getControllerObjectName()`. There is a member `controllerVendorName`, so I searched in Extbase for the setter of `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request::setControllerVendorName()`, precisely just for `setControllerVendorName`, and got a match in `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\RequestBuilder::build()`, where is a member called `vendorName`, and just in the method above `\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Web\RequestBuilder::loadDefaultValues()`, is the answer!

Answer (score 7):

Calling `tx_extbase_core_bootstrap` should no longer be used as it is [deprecated](http://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_tx___extbase___core___bootstrap.html) in ver. 6.0 and will be removed in 7.0

You can try different. Developers should now handle everything with namespaces ...

You can use this:

```
# bootstrap aufrufen -> run from extbase

userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
```

Comment: You're right, of course, but this does not solve my problem. Setting `vendorName = TYPO3` did, however.