# Assign plugin in typoscript

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.1.x

I have a plugin `http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/aw_consume`

I'm using it as a content element it's working

When I try to assign to a subpart in my typoscript nothing shows up

```
LOGOUT < plugin.tx_awconsume.widgets.menu
```

this plugin was created with the extension_builder extension installed on TYPO3 6.1.4

**update 3**

```
plugin.tx_awconsume {
    view {
        templateRootPath = {$plugin.tx_awconsume.view.templateRootPath}
        partialRootPath = {$plugin.tx_awconsume.view.partialRootPath}
        layoutRootPath = {$plugin.tx_awconsume.view.layoutRootPath}
    }
    persistence {
        storagePid = {$plugin.tx_awconsume.persistence.storagePid}
    }
    features {
        # uncomment the following line to enable the new Property Mapper.
        # rewrittenPropertyMapper = 1
    }

    widgets {
        menu = USER
        menu {
            userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
            pluginName = FeAwConsume
            extensionName = AwConsume
            controller = ConsumerItem
            action = list
            vendorName = Alexweb
        }
    }
}
```

ext_tables.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'FeAwConsume',
    'fe_awconsume'
);
```

ext_localconf.php

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Alexweb.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'FeAwConsume',
    array(
        'ConsumerItem' => 'list, show, new, create, delete',

    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'ConsumerItem' => 'create, delete',

    )
);
```

I have updated the code snippets according to @lorenz answer but im still getting no output

I have also pushed the latest version in TER 0.1.5

**update 4**

I did manage to get the expected output only after adding

```
plugin.tx_awconsume.widgets {
    menu = USER
    menu {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        pluginName = FeAwConsume
        extensionName = AwConsume
        controller = ConsumerItem
        action = list
        vendorName = Alexweb
    }
}
```

To the template typoscript file from `\typo3conf\ext\aw_consume\Configuration\TypoScript\setup.txt`

Where it was originally placed by the extension_builder extension however I got a feeling that this is not really a good idea

Comment: You need to bootstrap the plugin into container like showed in the  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14216781/1066240

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I bootstrap a plugin on TYPO3 CMS 6.0 with extbase?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061445/how-do-i-bootstrap-a-plugin-on-typo3-cms-6-0-with-extbase)

Comment: i'm afraid that didn't help much :(

Answer (score 2):

If you have a close look at your ext_localconf.php, you will notice that you use a vendor name. The vendor name should start with Uppercase so your **ext_localconf.php** should read:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Alexweb.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'MyPlugin',
    array(
        'ConsumerItem' => 'list, show, new, create, delete',        
    ),
    array(
        'ConsumerItem' => 'create, delete',     
    )
);
```

Your **ext_tables.php** should look like this:

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
    $_EXTKEY,
    'MyPlugin',
    'Speaking name of my plugin'
);
```

The TypoScript object of your plugin should include the vendor name (the property is vendorName, not vendor):

```
    userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
    pluginName = MyPlugin
    extensionName = AwConsume
    vendorName = Alexweb
    controller = ConsumerItem
    action = list
```

Keep in mind that your classes also must include the vendor name/make use of the correct namespace:

```
namespace Alexweb\AwConsume\Controller;

class ConsumerItemController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController {
}
```

Then you should be fine.

The extension name is the UpperCamelCase variant of your extension key, so if your extension key is "aw_consume", your extension name is "AwConsume". This name is used in the classes

The plugin name is the name of a particular plugin that is part of your extension. Since there can be many plugins in an extension, you should choose a fitting name for it. The plugin name should also be UpperCamelCase. You can have multiple plugins for the same controllers, therefore the plugin doesn't have to be named like the controller.

See also http://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3v4-mvc/wiki/FAQ#What-is-the-Extension-Name

Comment: i have followed your suggestions and updated my questions but still getting nothing

Comment: Try with an other extension plugin and see if it works there.

Comment: i have tried with `LANGUAGE_MENU < plugin.tx_srlanguagemenu.widgets.menu` and `SEARCH_BOX = COA_INT
        SEARCH_BOX {
            10 < plugin.tx_kesearch_pi1 }`  i can see them