# Include extbase plugin via typoscript, when having multiple plugins

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

In my extbase extension a have multiple plugins, in my ext_tables.php i have :

> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
>     $_EXTKEY,   'plugin1',  'Services du CSPQ' );
>
> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::registerPlugin(
>     $_EXTKEY,   'plugin2',  'plugin2' );

And in my ext_localconf.php :

> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
>     'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,    'plugin1',  array(
>                   'Test' => 'list, show',
>
> ),
>         // non-cacheable actions
>     array('Test' => '',) );
>
> \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
>     'TYPO3.' . $_EXTKEY,
>     'plugin2',
>     array(
>         'Test' => 'menu',
>     ),
>     // non-cacheable actions
>     array(
>         'Test' => '',
>         ) );

Now, how can i call the plugin2 by typoscript ?

for example, if i try to insert my plugin2 in lib.leftcontent, i tried this

```
 lib.leftcontent < plugin.tx_plugin2
```

but nothing happens!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 lib.leftcontent = USER
 lib.leftcontent {
        userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
        pluginName = Plugin2
        extensionName = MyExtension
        vendorName = Vendor
    }
```

Comment: No this is not the question, sorry if i'm not clear, my english is poor. I want to, for example, insert plugin2 in `lib.leftcontent`, if i try `lib.leftcontent < plugin.tx_plugin2 ` nothing happens!

Answer (score 1):

You first need to bootstrap your plugin as described in various article here on Stackoverflow, e.g. [How do I bootstrap a plugin on TYPO3 CMS 6.0 with extbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061445/how-do-i-bootstrap-a-plugin-on-typo3-cms-6-0-with-extbase). Start with

```
lib.leftcontent = USER
lib.leftcontent {
  userFunc      = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
  ...
```

and add all the other stuff as described in the linked article.

Answer (score 1):

dont forget actions. Like for tx.fe_manager

```
lib.userview = USER
lib.userview {
  userFunc = tx_extbase_core_bootstrap->run
  extensionName = Femanager

  pluginName =  Pi1
  vendorName = In2

  #controller = Edit 
  #action = edit

  switchableControllerActions {
        Edit {
          1 = edit
          2 = update
          3 = delete
          4 = confirmUpdateRequest

        }
  }

}
```