# “Could not analyse class: maybe not loaded or no autoloader?”

Tags: extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I have updated Typo3 v6.2.15 to 7.6.15 and tried to add namespaces to a custom Extension. Now im getting an error on the LoginController class:

> Could not analyse class: "Tx_Verwaltung_Controller_LoginController"
>   maybe not loaded or no autoloader? Class
>   Tx_Verwaltung_Controller_LoginController does not exist

What i have done:

- Replaced `$_EXTKEY` with `'DHW.' . $_EXTKEY` in these files: ext_localconf.php, ext_tables.php
  Example:

  ```
  \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
      'DHW.' . $_EXTKEY,
      'login',
      array(
          'Login' => 'loginbox,logoutbox'
      ),
      array(      
          'Login' => 'loginbox,logoutbox'
      )
  );
  ```
- added this in ext_emconfig.php:

  ```
  array(
      'classmap' => array('Classes'),
      'psr-4' => array('DHW\\Verwaltung\\' => 'Classes')
  ),
  ```
- added this in composer.json:

  ```
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "DHW\\Verwaltung\\": "Classes"
      }
  }
  ```
- added namespace in typo3conf/ext/verwaltung/Classes/LoginController.php

  ```
  namespace DHW\Verwaltung\Controller;

  class Tx_Verwaltung_Controller_LoginController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController { ... }
  ```
- Disabled and Enabled the Extension in Backend.
- Cleared caches in Backend.
- Deleted typo3temp folder
- Cleared caches with install tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it after reading this:
[How do I bootstrap a plugin on TYPO3 CMS 6.0 with extbase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061445/how-do-i-bootstrap-a-plugin-on-typo3-cms-6-0-with-extbase)

I had to add the vendorname in my Typoscript:

```
    loginBoxWidget = USER
    loginBoxWidget {
        userFunc = TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap->run
        vendorName    = DHW
        pluginName = login
        extensionName = Verwaltung
        controller = Login          
        action = loginbox

        ...
```

After that i got an "Fatal error: Cannot declare class" error. After renaming the class `Tx_Verwaltung_Controller_LoginController` to `LoginController` everything worked.